# Connection pool exhausted error (psycopg2)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am making an api that listens to webhook events , and every few hours I get "connection pool exhausted" error, which does not make any sense , since I am returning the connection to the pool at the end of each request

this is the python code

```py
POOL = SimpleConnectionPool(10, 20,database="chat", user='postgres', password='postgres', host='99.99.99.99', port='4567')
    
@csrf_exempt
def post(request):
    jned = json.loads(request.body)
    
    with POOL.getconn() as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                proxy_request(connection,cursor,jned)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                
            POOL.putconn(connection)

    
    return HttpResponse('OK')`
```

NOTE : the webhook that I am listening to has webhook-retires enabled
NOTE : the proxy_request() function calls external APIs which sometimes take a few seconds to respond
NOTE : once the connections-exhausted message comes up , it does not go away , and the server stops working , I think that this is happening because the external APIs that I am using are not fast , which causes the "connections exhausted error"

ANOTHER QUESTION: can I use max_lifetime when creating the connection pool to temporarily fix the problem ?

once the " connections exhausted " message comes up , I get a notification on whatsapp , and I manually restart the server , which is not scalable.

Comment: 1) Is that really `retires` or `retries`? 2) Per here [Pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html): *SimpleConnectionPool ... A connection pool that can’t be shared across different threads.*. Are their threads involved? 3) Have you checked logs for how many connections are actually being  made?  Maybe all you need to do is bump the `maxconn` a bit.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
1 - retries , sorry :)
2 - what do you mean by "are their threads involved?" 
3 - I don't think that matters , as "connection pool exhausted" means that there are 20 connections open at the same time (right ?)
4 - are you sure about that ? there's not a lot of people using it (max 10 requests/minute) , I think that 20 is already over-kill , is there a way to return the connection to the pool every 60 seconds (if proxy_request() is taking too much time) ?

Comment: 1) Not sure, that would need more investigation. My thought was threads would intefer with returning the connections. 4) The issue speaks for itself, you are running out of connections, hence allow more connections. That would need monitoring to make sure  that there is not an underlying issue that would cause that upper limit to just keep needing to be increased.  Some insight would probably be gained by updating question with the `proxy_request()` code.